# Is this Facebook id an group id?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there any way to know that Facebook ID is an id of group or not? 
For example: if id is bigger than 2.000.000.000.000 is a group id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the graph API call https://graph.facebook.com/ID there is a field called "type" which should give you the correct answer.

hope this helps